# Problema con fetch con el metodo post

Tags: javascript, fetch, headers

intento hacer una petición fetch con el método POST pero me sale un error, POST json.json 404 (Not Found), el recurso esta guardado en la misma carpeta que el código. En cambio si el método es GET todo funciona bien. ¿Porqué ocurre esto y como puedo solucionarlo?

```
my = new Headers({'Content-Type:'application/json'});
fetch(new Request('json.json', {method: 'POST'}).then(function(response){
response.json().then((data) => {console.log(data)})
})
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles para poder encontrar el problema. El mensaje de error 404 sólo indica que el recurso no está disponible para la solicitud realizada. ¿Sabes si el servidor acepta solicitudes tipo POST en esa dirección (`json.json`)? Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para que agregues más detalles. Saludos

Comment: Si si que acepta, y revisé el archivo json. Estaba todo correcto. Lo estoy haciendo en mi ordenador que no esta conectado a ninguna red.

Comment: A no ser que se haya manipulado de algún modo el código o la configuración del servidor, los errores 404 ocurren cuando intentas acceder a una URL o recurso que **no existe**. Si dices que cuando es por POST da error 404 y cuando es por GET funciona (supongo que hablamos de una petición a la misma URL), entonces deberías tener un [error 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405), que indicaría que intentas usar un método (POST en este caso) no permitido. OJO: no es revisando el archivo JSON como sabes si tu servidor admite o no el método POST u otro.

Comment: Por otra parte, si la petición devuelve un archivo `.json` como parece ser, lo propio es que uses el método `GET`, pues no estamos hablando de un archivo con extensión `.php` donde podrás mandar un body en la petición (para eso es el método POST), ni podrás mandar ningún tipo de dato. Al ser un archivo `.json` lo único que puedes es *obtenerlo*, nada más, por lo que el método apropiado aquí sería `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene errores:

- Construyes mal los headers. Cuando usas el constructor, debes pasar la información en la forma: `'Clave' : 'Valor'`, tú estás metiendo los dos puntos dentro de la parte que corresponde a la clave, lo cual es incorrecto.
- Tienes bloques no cerrados en tu código, lo cual también produciría error.
- No necesitas usar `Request` para este caso. [Lee la documentación para más detalles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Request).

Así debería funcionar (he puesto captura de errores, pues conviene implementar control de errores en el código, si no te interesa lo puedes quitar, pero no lo recomiendo):

```
var url = 'json.json';
var mHeaders = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers:mHeaders
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

De todos modos, aquí no tiene sentido una petición `POST`, pues no necesitas para este caso mandar datos en el `body`, por lo que `GET` sería suficiente.

Si aún así sigue dando error, deberás revisar tu configuración en el servidor, no el JSON en sí mismo, sino el servidor, el cual puede estar bloqueando las peticiones `POST`, aunque en ese caso lo propio sea un error `405`, no un error `404` el cual refiere siempe a una URL o recurso no encontrado.

Si no lo resuelves de este modo, comparte más información sobre tu entorno para poder ayudarte mejor.